# A question on Matrix limits

Tags: matrices, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider $M(n, \mathbb R)$ , the set of all real square matrices of size $n$ , as an NLS with norm

$||A||:=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2}=Trace(AA^t)$ , then is it true that a sequence of matrices $\{A_k=(a_{ij}^{(k)})\}$

in $M(n, \mathbb R)$ converges to $A=(a_{ij}) \in M(n, \mathbb R)$ iff the matrix entries $(a_{ij}^{(k)})$ converges to $a_{ij}$ as

$k \to \infty$ , $\forall i,j=1(1)n$ ?

Comment: Yes -- not that first the actual norm you use are all equivalent (you are in finite dimension), so you can show your result for whichever norm you want. One involving the coefficients will make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true.

One direction is easy, if $A=[a_{ij}]$ converges coordinate-wise to $B=[b_{ij}]$ then the norm certainly tends to zero.  On the other hand, if the norm is close to zero (say within $\epsilon$) then every entry differs by at most $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ since $\sum\sum(a_{ij}-b_{ij})^2 < \epsilon$ implies that $(a_{ij}-b_{ij})^2<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that for any $i,j$, $|a_{ij}^{(k)}-a_{ij}|\le\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i,j}{|a_{ij}^{(k)}-a_{ij}|^2}}=\|A_k-A\|\le n\cdot\max\limits_{i,j}|a_{ij}^{(k)}-a_{ij}|$. So for each $i,j$, $|a_{ij}^{(k)}-a_{ij}|\to0\implies n\cdot\max\limits_{i,j}|a_{ij}^{(k)}-a_{ij}|\to0\implies \|A_k-A\|\to 0$ and $\|A_k-A\|\to0\implies |a_{ij}^{(k)}-a_{ij}|\to0$, for each $i,j$.